# Передача двойного указателя в C++

Tags: указатели, c++

Добрый вечер.
Необходимо передать указатель на указатель в функцию (т.к в функции указатель будет изменяться), в C такая штука прокатывает без проблем, а вот C++ ругается. Как это обойти, или как правильней это все организовать?

```
struct list {
    int number;
    list *pNext;
    list *pPrev;
};

void init_queue(list **pBeg, list **pEnd) {
    (*pBeg) = 0x0;
    (*pEnd) = (*pBeg);
}
```

сам вызов:
     init_queue(&pBeg1, &pEnd1);

компилятор ругается вот так: `cannot convert ‘list*’ to ‘list**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void init_queue(list**, list**)’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, я предполагаю что pBeg1 и pEnd1 объявлены как

```
list * pBeg1, pEnd1; // звёздочка относится только к pBeg1
```

а надо

```
list * pBeg1, * pEnd1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, переменная pEnd1 у вас имеет тип list, а не list*.

Answer (score 0):

А еще мне не понятно, почему Вы показываете структуру, названную struct list, а дальше имеете дело с типом просто list? У Вас где-то идет переопределение типа?

Comment: Так в C++ не обязательно struct в имени типа писать.

Comment: Вах,  правда. Не знал. Сишное наследие.

Comment: Пережитки прошлого? struct -- аналог class со всеми полями и методами public.

Comment: @alexlz, это я знаю, я про обязательность слова struct писал.

Comment: Только Си - это не прошлое, а реально применяемый и живой язык, просто он...  другой немного.

Comment: Да это я как бы знаю.